# How to capture the console output of the external DLL in a PowerShell binary module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm creating a PowerShell binary module, and it uses the third-party library (DLL), which outputs to the console. So, basically I'd like my binary module to output both its own messages and the console output of that DLL.

Is it possible?

So, let's say the third-party API does the following:

```
public static void SomeMethod() {
  ...
  Console.Write("Extracting the file...");
  ...
}
```

The binary module calls it:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord() {
  ...
  this.WriteObject("Hello!");
  SomeClass.SomeMethod();
  this.WriteObject("Goodbye!");
}
```

The output I see is:

```
Hello!
Goodbye!
```

What I'd like to see is:

```
Hello!
Extracting the file...
Goodbye!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [System.Console.SetOut()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) method to temporarily set the current process's stdout to a text writer that you can read from.  You'll use Console.OpenStandardOutput() to reset the stdout back to the default after calling the DLL.  Look at the example on the SetOut topic page.

Comment: Yep, that works. Another challenge is to write and read the file at the same time, but that's another problem.